# Do AngularJS directives use output parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the example below, is the "ccSpinner" parameter and output parameter?  What they heck is it?  If not, how is the name being passed in but then duplicated on a function?  I've been going through AngularJS and JavaScript tutorials all week and nothing has explained this portion?

```
angular
    .module('app.widgets')
    .directive('ccSpinner', ['$window', ccSpinner]);

function ccSpinner($window) {
    // snip
};
```

[image]

Comment: Angular can be tricky and find out what $window means inside the ccSpinner function, but if you minify the file it doesn't work anymore. For it to work you use the array, and it one-to-one matches the array strings to the function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actual several things going on here.

### Global Scope

First `ccSpinner` is available on the global scope [implicitly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Implicit_globals_and_outer_function_scope). If you don't wrap your function declaration in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) it will implicitly be available globally.
Example in one JS File:

```
function globalAvailable() {
    console.log('this can be called anywhere');
}
```

Some other JS file:

```
globalAvailable(); // logs the above
```

### Hoisting

JavaScript has [variable and function hoisting](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting).

This essentially means that you can use a function before it shows up in your code. Basically the browser changes this:

```
hoistedFunction();

function hoistedFunction() {
   console.log('the above call still works');
}
```

to:

```
function hoistedFunction() {
   console.log('the above call still works');
}

hoistedFunction();
```

### Angular Dependency Injection

All of the above affects the line in question:

```
directive('ccSpinner', ['$window', ccSpinner]);
```

What this does is create a new `ccSpinner` directive that is available through the AngularJS framework.

Then this:`['$window', ccSpinner]` says that the `ccSpinner` directive requires `$window` and sets the `function ccSpinner` as the definition for the `ccSpinner` directive.

You could change the line to:

```
directive('awesomeSpinner', ['$window', ccSpinner]);
```

and use the new `awesomeSpinner` directive in places where you are using the existing `ccSpinner` directive and it will work the same way.

Comment: Hmm... interesting.  So, basically the JVM made the ccSpinner FUNCTION available in the scope (line 8) and it was being passed in to the directive function as a dependency (line 6).  It's only coincidence that the directive is also being named 'ccSpinner'.  Am I close?

Comment: You are absolutely right! You could change the `.directive` call to be `.directive('whateverSpinner',['$window', ccSpinner])` and change all of the places where you are using the `ccSpinner` and it will work the same way.

Comment: Thanks, Esteban.  The link you sent, with the doc on "hoisting," really helped.